# Changing styles using useState and useEffect

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, tailwind-css

I've had trouble trying to change the style from my `globals.css` file in my navbar. This is all so I can add an underline effect. The problem stems from the fact that the underline class defines the color of the text and I assume there is an easier way to do this as it's effectively making my `textColor` useState pointless and there is likely a way to simply connect the two files.

This is all to make sure the color of the underline, the text, and the background of the navbar changes after an initial scroll, from white text and underline with a transparent background to a white background with black text and underline.

Help appreciated :) Thanks.

**Navbar.js**

```
    const [nav, setNav] = useState(false);
    const [color, setColor] = useState('transparent');
    const [textColor, setTextColor] = useState('white');
    const [UnderlineColor, setUnderlineColor] = useState('underlinewhite');

    const handleNav = () => {
        setNav(!nav);
      };
    
      useEffect(() => {
        const changeColor = () => {
          if (window.scrollY >= 90) {
            setColor('#ffffff');
            setTextColor('#000000');
            setUnderlineColor('underlineblack');
          } else {
            setColor('transparent');
            setTextColor('#ffffff');
            setUnderlineColor('underlinewhite');
          }
        };
        window.addEventListener('scroll', changeColor);
      }, []);

  ...

  return ( 
        <div style={{ backgroundColor: `${color}` }} className='fixed left-0 top-0 w-full z-10 ease-in duration-300'>
            <div className='max-w-[1240px] m-auto flex justify-between items-center p-4 text-white'>
                <Link href='/'>
                    <h1 style ={{color: `${textColor}`}} className = 'font-bold text-4xl'>UTS</h1>
                </Link>
                <ul style ={{color: `${textColor}`}} className='hidden sm:flex'>
                    <li className={{UnderlineColor: `${setUnderlineColor}`}}>
                        <Link href='/'>Home</Link>
                    </li>
                    <li className='p-4 underlinewhite'>
                        <Link href='/#Services'>Our Services</Link>
                    </li>
                    <li className='p-4 underlinewhite'>
                        <Link href='/portfolio'>Work</Link>
                    </li>
                    <li className='p-4 underlinewhite'>
                        <Link href='/contact'>Contact</Link>
                    </li>
                </ul>

                ...
  )
```

Note: I have only tried to make the useState work for the home link and not for none of the others, which are working as intended.

**globals.css**

```css
.underlinewhite {
  position: relative;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.underlinewhite:hover {
  color: #fff;
}

.underlinewhite::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #fff;
  transform: scaleX(0);
  transition: transform 0.3s ease;
}

.underlinewhite:hover::before {
  transform: scaleX(1);
}

.underlineblack {
  position: relative;
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.underlineblack:hover {
  color: #000;
}

.underlineblack::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #000;
  transform: scaleX(0);
  transition: transform 0.3s ease;
}

.underlineblack:hover::before {
  transform: scaleX(1);
}
```

Comment: Why do you have a separate css file when you are using tailwind? Why not using tailwind classes instead?

Comment: I have tried that since but I still cant get my usestate value to effect the class color properties